# Dagger 2: инициализация AppComponent

Tags: android, dagger2

Всем привет!

Делаю тестовый проект с `Dagger 2`.

**Что получилось:**

Как я понял, нам нужно сделать 3 вещи для этой цели:

1. Создать нужный нам `@Module` (в моём примере он один), в котором запровайдить экземпляры нужных нам классов.
2. Создать `@Component`-класс, который будет являться неким рут-классом для наших модулей. В нём необходимо обозначить `Activity`, которые будут использовать зависимости данного компонента.
3. Нужно инициализировать `AppCpmponent` c помощью `DaggerAppComponent` и тем самым построить граф зависимостей. (Слегка необычно, но создаётся этот компонент на этапе первой компиляции - т.е., если начать его инициализировать - студия попросту не будет находить этот класс. Но после первой компиляции, он будет доступен.)

**Какие ошибки возникли:**

Смотрел разные мануалы на эту тему, почти везде одна схема:

`DaggerAppComponent` инициализирует наш `AppComponent` в отдельном классе `App`, который наследуется от `Application`.
Немного непонятно, зачем наследовать его от `Application` и инициализировать в `OnCreate` отдельного класса.
Сделав так, у меня возникла ошибка:

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface
>   method 'void
>   ru.alexbykov.dagger.dagger.AppComponent.inject(ru.alexbykov.dagger.MainActivity)'
>   on a null object reference
>                                                                            at ru.alexbykov.dagger.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:32)

Окей. Я подумал, что дело в том, что я инициализирую `DaggerAppComponent` не в том месте. (в методе `onCreate` класса `App`. Была уверенность, что он не вызывается.

Теста ради, решил проинициализировать его в отдельном статик-методе, который затем вызвал в `MainActivity` - все получилось.

**Вопрос:**

Как в итоге поступать правильно в будущих проектах при инициализации `AppComponent`? 
Почему во многих мануалах инициализация происходит в `onCreate` класса, наследуемого от `Application`?

---

*Код проекта, если кому интересно:*

**Module:**

```
@Module

public class DogModule {
    @Provides
    @NonNull
    @Singleton
    public Dog provideDog() {
        return new Dog("Pasha", 5);
    }
}
```

**Component:**

```
@Component(modules = DogModule.class)
@Singleton
public interface AppComponent {
    void inject(MainActivity mainActivity);
}
```

**App:**

```
public class App extends Application {




    public static AppComponent getComponent() {

         return DaggerAppComponent
                .builder()
                .dogModule(new DogModule())
                .build();

    }

//    @Override
//    public void onCreate() {
//        super.onCreate();
//        component = buildComponent();
//    }
//
//
//    protected AppComponent buildComponent() {
//
//
//        return DaggerAppComponent
//                .builder()
//                .dogModule(new DogModule())
//                .build();
//    }




}
```

**MainActivity:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {



    @Inject
    Dog dog;

    TextView tw;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

      App.getComponent().inject(this);

        tw = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tw1);
        tw.setText(dog.getName());
    }
}
```

Comment: ваш `App` в манифесте прописан?

Comment: @ermak0ff да, не был прописан. Спасибо)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В Application его инициализируют для того, чтобы компонент билдился ровно один раз, если вы уверены, что создав его в методах MainActivity он не будет проинициализирован еще раз, можете билдить его там.

В вашем коде выходит что компонент каждый раз создается по новой, предположу что при нескольких inject'ах в компоненте, код не будет работать как надо.

Вот фрагмент инициализации из моего кода:

```
public class App extends Application {
    private static AppComponent component;


    public static AppComponent getComponent() {
        return component;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        component = buildComponent();
    }

    protected AppComponent buildComponent() {
        return DaggerAppComponent.builder()
                .appModule(new AppModule(getApplicationContext()))
                .presenterModule(new PresenterModule())
                .viewModule(new ViewModule())
                .build();
    }
}
```

В манифесте не забудьте указать имя класса, который наследовали от Application, :

```
<application
    android:name="com.example.testapp.App"
    ... >

    ...
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! 
Только у меня меня в таком случае возникает ошибка. (Лог в вопросе), т.к. `onCreate` у `App` не вызывается.Как исправить эту проблему?

Comment: Возможно у вас в манифесте не указано имя унаследованного от Application класса, добавил в ответ

Comment: спасибо) теперь стало намного понятнее)